# Alterar conteúdo de arquivo com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Olá, primeiramente, gostaria de esclarecer que procurei tanto aqui no stack, como em outros sites algo que respondesse à minha pergunta, porém não encontrei.
A minha dúvida é, como posso reescrever o conteúdo de um arquivo JSON do servidor usando AJAX ? No caso, eu consigo pegar o conteúdo dele e utilizar no browser normalmente, porém, ao alterar algo no browser, gostaria de salvar/sobrescrever as alterações no arquivo original.

Código Atual:

JSON

```
[{
    "nome":"Borin Gnur",
    "profissao":"Bibliotecário",
    "imagem":"img/borin.png"
}, (...)]
```

JS

```
var personagensJSON;
function recuperaPersonagens(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            return personagensJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "personagens.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
    //selecaoPersonagem();
}
```

Comment: Você precisará de uma linguagem no lado do servidor analisando a requisição e escrevendo no arquivo. Com PHP, poderia utilizar o `file_put_contents`, por exemplo.

Comment: Cara, eu já te expliquei no chat que isso é impossível.

Comment: Eu não disse que não quero usar o PHP, eu disse que por enquanto não estou usando, justamente por isso postei a pergunta, para descobrir uma forma de fazer isso '-'

Comment: @LINQ, por isso postei a pergunta, para ver quais as opções que tenho com outras linguagens '-'

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Perl :p

Comment: PERL e PHP até onde sei

Comment: qualquer uma das linguagens, na pergunta, só deixei informado que não fiz a utilização de PHP em nenhum momento

Comment: retirei de lá pra não causar mais confusão aheuahe

Comment: Agora outro detalhe: você já está fazendo uma requisição POST com os novos dados ao servidor ou tem dificuldade nesta parte também? Se sim, pode colocar na pergunta?

Comment: justamente isso, assim como está na pergunta, eu quero saber como realizar isso, a alteração do conteúdo e tal, não estou fazendo nenhuma requisição adicional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é:

> alterar algo no browser, gostaria de salvar/sobrescrever as alterações no arquivo original.

O que você tem que fazer é realizar as alterações no browser, e então enviar (possivelmente via AJAX) o arquivo alterado ao servidor para que o servidor o salve (provavelmente usando um dos verbos HTTP POST, PUT ou PATCH).

O servidor deverá disponibilizar um serviço para este propósito, além de lidar com as devidas questões de autenticação e autorização (para evitar que usuários mal-intencionados venham a bagunçar com os arquivos do servidor).

Não é possível salvar diretamente sem ser por intermédio do servidor. O motivo é que o arquivo é modificado no navegador de um determinado computador (ou celular ou coisa semelhante) **X** e ele deve ser salvo no sistema de arquivos do computador **Y**. Não há forma de fazer os dados que estão em **X** aparecerem em **Y** sem que esses sejam enviados de alguma forma do dispositivo **X** até o dispositivo **Y**, e a melhor forma de enviá-los é justamente por meio do HTTP, que é o protocolo já utilizado pelo navegador que está rodando em **X** em um site disponibilizado via HTTP pelo servidor **Y**.